# Updated rewrite rule in htaccess, getting error 404 in google web master tools

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I changed one of my rewrite rule with new structure and now I'm notice error **404** in Google web master tools to all of my pages.

Old rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^channel.([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)-([a-z]+)$ channel.php?user=$1&q=$2
```

New rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^channel:([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$ channel.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Now I'm getting a lot of error **404** for all pages with old rewrite rule. I got custom 404 page and correctly return header not found, but Google still report me errors. How can I fix it?
sorry for my bad English, but really need to fix this...

Comment: On the left, is that a literal period/dot after "channel", or is it a wildcard? If it's literally a ., it must be \.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about before and after effect but your **regex is incorrect** where you have unescaped hyphen in the middle. An hyphen needs to be at 1st or last position to avoid escaping in character class.

Use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^channel.([\w-]+)-([a-z]+)$ channel.php?user=$1&q=$2 [L,QSA]
```

OR:

```
RewriteRule ^channel:([\w-]+)$ channel.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It would be better to know the URLs you're trying to match using these rules.

**EDIT:** As per comments use this rule to block old URLs:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+channel\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^channel\.([^-]+) /channel:$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Im using only new rewrite rule, because if are both will have duplicate content. That rule work fine, but google still crawls pages with old URLs and report me errors 404. How can i tell to googlebot stop crawls this pages...

Comment: Since 0-9 is already a range, is `-_` really going to be interpreted as "nine through underscore"? Even if not, it would still be clearer to change it to `_-`.

Comment: Now everythnig is ok, it has only little small problem. When access old url like: domain.com/channel.user-song is redirecting to domain.com/channel:user-song I just want to be domain.com/channel:user Thank u again.